# Marshal.ReleaseComObject throws exception

Tags: c#, interop, com-interop, comvisible

Trying to use a COM visible .NET class via other .NET application and get exception:

> Message: The object's type must be
>   __ComObject or derived from __ComObject.
>
> Parameter name: o
>
> Stack Trace:    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Object
>   o)

The class looks as follows:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IViewer : IComInteropDefinedInterface
{
}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("[some guid]")]
public class MyViewer : UserControl, IViewer    
{
    //IViewer implementation
}
```

I register the component with:

```
regasm [Assembly Path] /tlb /codebase
```

The client application, which is also in .NET instantiates successfully the given class, but when he calls`Marshal.ReleaseComObject()` it gets the exception described above.

Any idea for solving this problem?

**EDIT:**
Unfortunately I can't provide the client application code for instantiating my object. However I know the client is using the same method to instantiate real COM objects.

Comment: Can you include the code where your are instantiating the object and where you are calling `ReleaseComObject` too? What type has the object you are releasing? It seems that is it not a COM object. And as an aside: What is the reason that you want to use COM in this case? Using a .NET assembly from .NET works much easier without COM (and actually I have the suspicion that you are already doing so ;-)

Comment: Can you post the client code, it would be good to see how the component is being instantiated

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide the client application code for instantiating my object. However I know the client is using the same method to instantiate real COM objects.

Answer (score 3):

I got this problem recently, when reimplementing a native COM to managed code.
The solution was to ask if the object is a native COM with Marshal.IsComObject, only native COMs must be release with Marshal.ReleaseComObject.

This is code:

```
if (Marshal.IsComObject(comObject))
{
     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(comObject);
}
comObject = null;
```

**Important**: you have to be sure, no use that object after been Released.

For a more detailed explanation read this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous.aspx

Comment: That blog post is pretty specific about Marshal.IsComObject() **not** being the proper solution.

Comment: That blog post says that the **Marshal.IsComObject() solution CAN be used if we are CERTAIN that the comObject IS NOT and WILL NEVER be used somewhere else** after it is released, even after a code refactoring... When unsure then it is better not releasing it at all (by hand) and let the garbage collector do it somewhen...

Answer (score 0):

But how are you creating the class instance?  Simply using the expression `new MyViewer()` doesn't create a COM object.  Instead it creates a plain old .Net object which cannot be used with the ReleaseComObject method.

Based on your sample code, in particular the line about `MyViewer` having an implementation, it doesn't sound like you're dealing with a COM object.  Instead it looks like you have a managed object which implements a COM interface.

In order to use the ReleaseComObject you'd need to actually have a COM / RCW object.

Comment: If the assembly containing `MyViewer` was added as a COM reference, wouldn't you rather get a COM object with `new MyViewer()` then (instead of a plain old .NET object)? I can't think of a reason why to do so but it *might* be possible.

Comment: @0xA3 yes if this type was a CoClass in a PIA (at least AFAIK).  But in this case it's just a plain old managed object so new isn't doing anything special.

Comment: doesn't COM registered .NET class mean having an object that implements all the basic COM functionality including Release?

Comment: @Aaron it depends on which part of the object.  The .Net side doesn't have the Add/Release methods because it's simple not necessary on a .Net object.  The CCW (COM callable wrapper) which is generated by the CLR will have them out of necessity.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you are actually not using COM but simply use a referenced .NET class. If your project contains code like

```
MyViewer viewer = new MyViewer();
```

and you have added the library containing `MyViewer` not as a COM reference, you are actually not using COM.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather try:

```
if (comObject != null)
{
      if (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.IsComObject(comObject))
      {                
          System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(comObject);
      }
      comObject= null;
}
```